# using mwclient under proxy server

Tags: python, proxy

I use net under proxy server

```
 self.wp = site if site else mwclient.Site(self.url)
```

when above line is encountered following errors are show

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mwclient-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\mwclient\client.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.site_init()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mwclient-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\mwclient\client.py", line 100, in site_init
    siprop = 'general|namespaces', uiprop = 'groups|rights')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mwclient-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\mwclient\client.py", line 165, in api
    info = self.raw_api(action, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mwclient-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\mwclient\client.py", line 248, in raw_api
    json_data = self.raw_call('api', data).read()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mwclient-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\mwclient\client.py", line 223, in raw_call
    url, data = data, headers = headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mwclient-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\mwclient\http.py", line 225, in post
    return self.find_connection(host).post(host,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mwclient-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\mwclient\http.py", line 218, in find_connection
    conn = cls(host, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mwclient-0.6.5-py2.7.egg\mwclient\http.py", line 62, in __init__
    self._conn.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 757, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I tried setting proxy using urllib2 by following steps, but it didnt help

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> auth = 'http://xxxxx:xxxx@10.1.9.30:8080'
>>> handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http':auth})
>>> opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
>>> urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

Comment: How do you think mwclient knows about this opener? I have not used mwclient but looking at its code I think its not urllib2 at all. Can you elaborate , perhaps post more of your code

Comment: mwclient uses httplib.HTTPConnection fuction which is showing error cause i did not the proxy environment

Comment: @perpetual: That is the problem here; to support a proxy, you need to rework the whole `mwclient` codebase. It does not support proxies as it stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit old, but I faced the same problem yesterday and I'm posting the solution here, as it may help other people.

I managed to sort it out by changing the file mwclinet/http.py. Basically I check if the environment variable `http_proxy` exists and connect through a proxy rather than directly.

In class `class HTTPPersistentConnection(object):` I added a variable `usesProxy = False`. Around line 61 I replaced `self._conn = self.http_class(host)` by:

```
    http_proxy_env = os.environ.get('http_proxy')
    if http_proxy_env is not None:
      try:
        # proxy
        http_proxy_url = urlparse.urlparse(http_proxy_env)
        http_proxy_host,http_proxy_port = http_proxy_url.netloc.split(':')
        self._conn = self.http_class(http_proxy_host,int(http_proxy_port))
        self.usesProxy=True;
      except:
        self._conn = self.http_class(host)
    else: 
      self._conn = self.http_class(host)
```

Then I substituted the next 2 occurrences of: `self._conn.request(method, path, ....)`. 
At line 94 by :

```
  if self.usesProxy is False:
    self._conn.request(method, path, headers = headers)
  else:
    self._conn.request(method, "http://"+host+path, headers = headers)
```

and at line 107 by:

```
if self.usesProxy is False:
  self._conn.request(method, path, data, headers)
else:
  self._conn.request(method, "http://"+host+path, data, headers)
```

It should do the job!